# Update D3 Line Graph from List Options

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I manipulate a JSON string and I present the data in a fully responsive D3 Line Graph. I am also creating a vertical list with the unique values of a specific item of the original JSON object.

When I click on the values of the vertical list, I want the chart to change/update with the new values. I have created some functions which are easy to read in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radomer/n5ko9hwg/) and also pasted the same code in a snippet below. At the bottom of the question, I have pasted the function that needs to change to make the whole thing work where I also added some comments.

```js
//JSON Data
data = [
  {
    "date": "2008-11",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2008-11",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2008-12",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 8.3
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-01",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 8.7
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-02",
    "Value": "C",
    "num": 8.9
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-03",
    "Value": "D",
    "num": 9.2
  }
];

//Parses date for correct time format
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

//Format data for the filter list (or dropdown) function
function formatData(data) {

  var valueMap = {}; //DROPDOWN
  var mainFields = ["date", "num"]; //DROPDOWN
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.num = +d.num;

    var Value = d.Value; //DROPDOWN
    valueMap[Value] = []; //DROPDOWN
    mainFields.forEach(function(field) { //DROPDOWN
      valueMap[Value].push( d[field] ); //DROPDOWN
    }); //DROPDOWN
 });
  
  return valueMap;
}

createChart(data);

//Create a global variable 
var valueMap= formatData(data);

//Dropdown creation function
function dropDown(valueMap){

  // Handler for dropdown value change
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {

  var newData   = data;
    for (var i = newData.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (newData[i].Value != d) {
            newData.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

    d3.select("svg").remove();
    createChart(newData);
    return newData;    
    //Update Lines function below
    
  };

  // Get names of Campaigns, for dropdown 
  var campaigns = Object.keys(valueMap).sort();  //DROPDOWN

  var dropdown = d3.select("#dropdown")   //DROPDOWN
  .insert("ul", "svg")   //DROPDOWN
  .classed('selector', true);  //DROPDOWN


  dropdown.selectAll("li")   //DROPDOWN
    .data(campaigns)   //DROPDOWN
    .enter().append("li")   //DROPDOWN
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.Value; })   //DROPDOWN
    .text(function (d) {   //DROPDOWN
    return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1,d.length); // capitalize 1st letter   //DROPDOWN
  })   //DROPDOWN
    .on("click", dropdownChange);   //DROPDOWN
    //.on("click", dropdownChange);   //DROPDOWN

  var initialData = valueMap[ campaigns[0] ];   //DROPDOWN
}

//Call the function
dropDown(valueMap);

//Create chart function
function createChart(data){
//Margin conventions
var margin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50};
var widther = (window.innerWidth)*2/3;
var width = widther - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//Divides date for tooltip placement
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;    
//Appends the svg to the chart-container div
var svg = d3.select(".g-chart").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//Creates the xScale 
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);
//Creates the yScale
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
//Defines the y axis styles
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(yScale)
  .tickSize(-width)
  .tickPadding(8)
 .orient("left");
//Defines the y axis styles
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(xScale)
  .tickPadding(8)
 .orient("bottom")
 .tickSize(height)
  .ticks(numTicks(width))
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%Y")); 
//line function convention (feeds an array)
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.num); });    

 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.num = +d.num;
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 });

  //Appends chart headline
 d3.select(".g-hed").text("Chart Perfect");
  //Appends chart intro text
  d3.select(".g-intro").text("41604 ");
  data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date - b.date; });
  //Defines the xScale max
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  //Defines the yScale max
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.num; }));
 //Appends the y axis
 var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
 //Appends the x axis  
 var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);
  //Binds the data to the line
  var drawline = svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);     
  //Tooltips
  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");
  //Adds circle to focus point on line
  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4);
  //Adds text to focus point on line    
  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");    
  //Creates larger area for tooltip   
  var overlay = svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);
  //Tooltip mouseovers            
  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d.num) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(d.num);
  }; 
  //Appends chart source
 d3.select(".g-source-bold")
    .text("SOURCE: ")
    .attr("class", "g-source-bold");

  d3.select(".g-source-reg")
    .text("Chart source info goes here")
    .attr("class", "g-source-reg");  
  //RESPONSIVENESS
  d3.select(window).on("resize", resized);

  function resized() {
    //new margin
    var newMargin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50};
    //Get the width of the window
    var w = d3.select(".g-chart").node().clientWidth;
    console.log("resized", w);
    //Change the width of the svg
    d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", w);
    //Change the xScale
    xScale
      .range([0, w - newMargin.right]);
    //Update the line
    line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.num); }); 
    d3.selectAll('.line')
      .attr("d", line);  
    //Updates xAxis
    xAxisGroup
      .call(xAxis);   
    //Updates ticks
    xAxis
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(numTicks(w));

    //Updates yAxis  
    yAxis
      .tickSize(-w - newMargin.right)
  };
//Determines number of ticks base on width
function numTicks(widther) {
  if (widther <= 900) {
    return 4
    console.log("return 4")
  }
  else {
    return 12
    console.log("return 5")
  }
}

}
```

```css
.axis text,.g-labels,body{font-family:Proxima-Nova,sans-serif}body{font-size:12px}.flex-container{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-around}.flex-item1,.flex-item2{height:auto;margin-top:10px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.flex-item1{background:tomato;width:33%}.flex-item2{width:67%}.g-hed,.g-source-bold{text-align:left;font-weight:700}.g-hed{text-transform:uppercase;font-size:22px;margin:3px 0}.g-source-bold{font-size:10px}.g-source{margin:10px 0}.g-intro{font-size:16px;margin:0 0 10px}.g-labels{fill:#fff;font-weight:700;font-size:14px}.axis line{fill:none;stroke:#ccc;stroke-dasharray:2px 3px;shape-rendering:crispEdges;stroke-width:1px}.axis text{font-size:13px;pointer-events:none;fill:#7e7e7e}.focus,.y.axis text{font-size:14px}.y.axis text{text-anchor:end!important;fill:#7e7e7e}.domain{display:none}.line{stroke:#2f5491;stroke-width:3px;fill:none}.overlay{fill:none;pointer-events:all}.focus circle{fill:#5e8dc9}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item1"><div id="dropdown"></div></li>
    <li class="flex-item2">

      <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
      <p class="g-intro"></p>
      <div class="g-chart"></div>
        <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span>
      </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

This part below needs to change (unless you have a better idea) where I need to reset the SVG of the graph and re-create it.

```
  // Handler for dropdown value change
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {

        var newData   = data;
    for (var i = newData.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (newData[i].Value != d) {
            newData.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

    d3.select("svg").remove();
    createChart(newData);
    return newData;    
    //Update Lines function below

  };
```

Comment: Do you basically want to be able to click on the 'A' / 'B' / 'C' / 'D' to load the relevant data into your line chart?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Yes. The dropdown will be dynamic (if the value A does not exist, it won't appear). Then, if I click on the value, I should see the data for all the items of the JSON objects that contain the value "A" (if I click on the A). In this case, in my JSON, I have two lines for the "A" value.

Comment: What are you going to do about the chart scaling when you filter the data? At the moment, the code is not written to take into account any updates that might occur. Have you written a function that will perform the appropriate updates to the chart when the filter is activated?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have created an answer that works for me. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and an advice from a JS developer, I managed to create the following:

```js
//JSON Data
const data = [
{
    "date": "2008-11",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-11",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2008-12",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 8.3
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-01",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 8.7
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-02",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 8.9
  },
  {
    "date": "2009-03",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 9.2
  }
];

//Parses date for correct time format
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

//Format data for the filter list (or dropdown) function
function formatData(data) {

  var valueMap = {}; //DROPDOWN
  var mainFields = ["date", "num"]; //DROPDOWN
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.num = +d.num;

    var Value = d.Value; //DROPDOWN
    valueMap[Value] = []; //DROPDOWN
    mainFields.forEach(function(field) { //DROPDOWN
      valueMap[Value].push(d[field]); //DROPDOWN
    }); //DROPDOWN
  });

  return valueMap;
}

//Dropdown creation function
function dropDown() {

  // Handler for dropdown value change
  const valueMap = formatData(data);
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {
  

    d3.select("svg").remove();
    const newData = data.filter(function(item){
      return item.Value == d;
   });
    
    d3.select(this).style("color", "#c7003b");
    createChart(newData);
 
    //Update Lines function below

  };

  // Get names of Campaigns, for dropdown 
  var campaigns = Object.keys(valueMap).sort(); //DROPDOWN

  var dropdown = d3.select("#dropdown") //DROPDOWN
    .insert("ul", "svg") //DROPDOWN
    .classed('selector', true) //DROPDOWN



  dropdown.selectAll("li") //DROPDOWN
    .data(campaigns) //DROPDOWN
    .enter().append("li") //DROPDOWN
     .attr("id", (function(d) { //DROPDOWN
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length); // capitalize 1st letter   //DROPDOWN
    }))
    .text(function(d) { //DROPDOWN
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length); // capitalize 1st letter   //DROPDOWN
    }) //DROPDOWN
    .on("click", dropdownChange);//DROPDOWN
    


  var initialData = valueMap[campaigns[0]]; //DROPDOWN

  
}

//Create chart function
function createChart(data) {
  //Margin conventions
  var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  };
  var widther = (window.innerWidth) * 2 / 3;
  var width = widther - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  //Divides date for tooltip placement
  var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }).left;
  //Appends the svg to the chart-container div
  var svg = d3.select(".g-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  //Creates the xScale 
  var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
  //Creates the yScale
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
  //Defines the y axis styles
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickPadding(8)
    .orient("left");
  //Defines the y axis styles
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickPadding(8)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(height)
    .ticks(numTicks(width))
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%Y"));
  //line function convention (feeds an array)
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.num);
    });

  
  let mappedData = data.map(function(d) {
    const num = +d.num;
    const  date = parseDate(d.date);
    return {
    num, date
    }
  });

  //Appends chart headline
  d3.select(".g-hed").text("Chart Perfect");
  //Appends chart intro text
  d3.select(".g-intro").text("41604 ");
  mappedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });
  //Defines the xScale max
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(mappedData, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  //Defines the yScale max
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(mappedData, function(d) {
    return d.num;
  }));
  //Appends the y axis
  var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
  //Appends the x axis  
  var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);
  //Binds the mappedData to the line
  var drawline = svg.append("path")
    .datum(mappedData)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
  //Tooltips
  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");
  //Adds circle to focus point on line
  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4);
  //Adds text to focus point on line    
  focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
  //Creates larger area for tooltip   
  var overlay = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);
  //Tooltip mouseovers            
  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
      i = bisectDate(mappedData, x0, 1),
      d0 = mappedData[i - 1],
      d1 = mappedData[i],
      d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d.num) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(d.num);
  };
  //Appends chart source
  d3.select(".g-source-bold")
    .text("SOURCE: ")
    .attr("class", "g-source-bold");

  d3.select(".g-source-reg")
    .text("Chart source info goes here")
    .attr("class", "g-source-reg");
  //RESPONSIVENESS
  d3.select(window).on("resize", resized);

  function resized() {
    //new margin
    var newMargin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 80,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 50
    };
    //Get the width of the window
    var w = d3.select(".g-chart").node().clientWidth;
    console.log("resized", w);
    //Change the width of the svg
    d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", w);
    //Change the xScale
    xScale
      .range([0, w - newMargin.right]);
    //Update the line
    line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.num);
      });
    d3.selectAll('.line')
      .attr("d", line);
    //Updates xAxis
    xAxisGroup
      .call(xAxis);
    //Updates ticks
    xAxis
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(numTicks(w));

    //Updates yAxis  
    yAxis
      .tickSize(-w - newMargin.right)
  };
  //Determines number of ticks base on width
  function numTicks(widther) {
    if (widther <= 900) {
      return 4
      console.log("return 4")
    } else {
      return 12
      console.log("return 5")
    }
  }

}

createChart(data);

dropDown();
```

```css
  /*css to go here*/

  body {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .flex-item1 {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .flex-item2 {
    width: 67%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .g-hed {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .g-source {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .g-intro {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }

  .g-labels {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    fill: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .g-chart {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .g-chart svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px 3px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .axis text {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .y.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .domain {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    stroke: #2f5491;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    fill: none;
  }

  .overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .focus {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .focus circle {
    fill: #5e8dc9;
  }

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .selector li {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #fff;
 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="dropdown"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">

    <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
    <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```